# Magento registration form modification

Tags: magento2, email, customer-registration, login-register, mobile-login

My client asking a requirement for replacing email as mobile number with OTP verification. Is there any ways to remove email from required fields. If so it would cause any issue on checkout or order processing.

Comment: Check this module https://github.com/magestat/magento2-sign-in-with-phone-number